# Transform a list into a sentence

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python but I had a simple problem in one of my projects. I have a list made of string of characters:

```
그러니까, 네놈들은
이 무덤의 주인이
아니란 말이냐?
```

When I print with readlines(), i get:

```
['그러니까, 네놈들은\n', '이 무덤의 주인이\n', '아니란 말이냐?']
```

But what I would like to have is:

```
그러니까, 네놈들은 이 무덤의 주인이 아니란 말이냐?
```

No line jump, and only a space between the lines content.

I think the solution is quite simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I already found some leads but nothing seems to work in my case and I don't know why (I'm probably doing something wrong). These are the leads I already tried but with no success:

1. Count the number of lines and use a "for"loop to add up all the elements
2. Convert a list to string
3. Try to delete some characters (\n)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = ['그러니까, 네놈들은\n', '이 무덤의 주인이\n', '아니란 말이냐?']
' '.join(w.strip() for w in lst)
```